# Run command after prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, command

I created a *flirt.sh* script which just outputs a random sentence with a random color, and now I want it to be ran every time I enter a command

I used `trap "~/flirt.sh" DEBUG` in `.bashrc` for that purpose but there's a small problem:

```
for i in 1; do
    echo $i
done
```

runs *flirt.sh* two times, and if I use `for i in {1..2}` the output will be 2 times from script and 1, after that another 2 times from script and 2 e.g., so *for each command in loop it runs script 2 times*. I'm searching for a method to run command (script) **one time** after I press enter and **before** command I typed starts executing, so something like this:

```
# Nothing typed so script won't be executed
$
# Script and command will be executed
$ ls
Hello from flirt.sh!

Documents Downloads
...

# Script will be executed only once
$ for i in {1..2}; do echo $i; done
Hello from flirt.sh!

1
2
```

Any tips, please?

Comment: After every command (as you've asked), or actually for every shell prompt?

Comment: For every shell prompt only, as I’ve described in my example

Comment: This Q/A is very useful for revealing the witchcraft that is the trap command. I find this to be the answer to my own related question: how to achieve _hiding the cursor during command execution_ and showing it again later. (Hint use escape sequences `\e[?25l`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've clarified in a comment that you really want the command to run only for every prompt. What isn't directly available in `bash` is, "*a method to run command […] after I press enter and before command I typed starts executing*". However, a work-around is available using `trap '…' DEBUG`.

Here are two suggestions for you

1. `PROMPT_COMMAND`. This feature runs a command immediately *before* each prompt. The documentation for `bash` (see `man bash`) writes,

   > **`PROMPT_COMMAND`** If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

   Examples

   ```
   PROMPT_COMMAND='date'
   PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "Date: %s Id: %s\n" "$(date)" "$(id -un)"'
   PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "Command 1"; echo "Command 2"'
   ```
2. `trap '…' DEBUG`. As you have already discovered this will allow you to run a command immediately before it's executed. The documentation writes for `trap`,

   > If a sigspec is `DEBUG`, the command arg is executed before every simple command, `for` command, `case` command, `select` command, every arithmetic `for` command, and before the first command executed in a shell function

   So, what we can do here is to have the trap run your `Flirt.sh` command only once after each prompt, using a toggle to suppress it after the first time until the next prompt is received.

   ```
   PROMPT_COMMAND='_trace=yes'
   trap '[[ "$_trace" == "yes" ]] && echo Flirt.sh; _trace=no' DEBUG
   ```

   Here I've used `echo Flirt.sh` as a substitute for your `flirt.sh` script.

   Sample session

   ```
   $ date
   Flirt.sh
   28 Jan 2022 16:57:51
   $ for i in 1 2 3; do echo i=$i; done
   Flirt.sh
   i=1
   i=2
   i=3
   $
   ```
3. Do not trigger when there’s no command

   Adding a simple check for `$BASH_COMMAND` can preserve from miss-trigger

   ```sh
   trap 'cmd="$BASH_COMMAND"; [[ "$cmd" != "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]] && echo ~/.Flirt.sh' DEBUG
   ```

Comment: Please correct COMMAND_PROMPT to PROMPT_COMMAND, and I have a question, can I make it not to trigger if I didn’t type any commend (just pressed enter)?

Comment: @xezo360hye thank you for pointing out that typo. Incidentally, you would have been welcome to [edit the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/688350/edit) and fix it. I did have a look around to see if I could avoid a trigger on an empty command but I couldn't get anywhere, even with `extdebug`, `$ARGC`, and `$BASH_COMMAND`

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it myself, if I could find something I’ll add to answer. Also I didn’t know that I can edit somebody’s answer, thank you for that

Comment: Does enabling this debug option have any significant impact on the performance, or any side effects an user should be aware of?

Comment: @Neinstein I would expect that any significant difference would be from the impact of the code that the trap runs, more than the presence of the trap itself. It shouldn't affect the execution of `bash` scripts, so the impact will be seen, if at all, only for interactive use